# Auto complete textbox suggestions in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I implemented auto complete in vb.net textbox  , but there is an issue that when user types something in text box the auto complete suggestion list blinks and disappears like if the focus changed

here is the code:

```
        Dim Bl As New ItemBL
        Dim suggestions = DAL.DisplayLikeNameList(Trim(MyTextBox.Text))
        Dim MySource As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
        MySource.AddRange(suggestions.ToArray)

        With MyTextBox
            .AutoCompleteCustomSource = MySource
            .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
            .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        End With
    End If
```

I believe the problem in  Mdi form because it has timer code executed after the above code :

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    LblDateAndTime.Text = Now
End Sub
```

Note: the auto complete code is executed in a child form not in the Mdi Form , what do you suggest to keep suggestions list "sticky" as the user writing in the text box ??

Comment: Have you tried to comment out the Timer event to see if the suggestions list remains open?

Comment: well ,I did , the same problem  exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue ,

This Code was written in 
   `Key_Up` event
but now I wrote it in `Text_Changed` Event and it worked

Comment: hey, @Abid Qasem,...  did you found any problem when u use the suggestion appearance once the text_changed function called? I have an exception around here.... due to the accessing suggestion list run time.... :(