# TextBox AutoComplete not working in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, autocomplete

I'm trying to add auto complete to a VB.NET windows forms textbox. 
I have a text box of size 268, 102 placed on a form. I have tried several ways to get the autocomplete to work: 
Adding strings to the  AutoCompleteCustomSource via the Properties pane
Adding a list of strings to a source and assigning that in code - multiple different ways
Neither of these make any autocompleteing happen...

Most recent code attempt is pretty much the example shown on MSDN:

```
Dim I2cMonths As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    '...
    I2cMonths.AddRange(New String() {"January", "Febuary", "March"})
    With I2C_TextBox
        .AutoCompleteCustomSource = I2cMonths
        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    End With
    '...
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: write that in text changed event and check

Comment: @akhilkumar Im not sure what you mean, can you explain a bit?

Comment: i mean set the property in the textbox's text_changed event.not in formload.

Comment: saw some sugestions like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572432/auto-complete-textbox-suggestions-in-vb-net

Comment: @akhilkumar great, but no change :(

Comment: @Toby so I started a new project dropped a new textbox control on the form and tried both your code and mine and they both worked just fine. Is there something you may be leaving out or changing somewhere else? At this point I am not sure what could be happening...

Comment: Oh. Hm Im not sure what that might be but I didn't think of looking for interference from other settings.. Thanks for Your effort! I'll have a hunt around on that

Comment: @Toby ok, good luck! Report back and let us know if you found the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your description of the case, I suspect your TextBox is MULTILINE.
Standard AutoComplete doesn't work in multiline textboxes.

If you want AutoComplete in a multiline textbox, you'll have to implement it yourself using the appropriate events of the TextBox and processing an on-the-fly list(view)-"pop-up" or some other equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order around...

```
     I2C_TextBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    12C_Textbox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
       I2cMonths.AddRange(New String() {"January", "Febuary", "March"})        
     12C_TextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = 12cMonths
```

Comment: Not seeing any difference with that I'm afraid :\

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
    I2cMonths.AddRange(New String() {"January", "Febuary", "March"})     
    With I2C_TextBox 
       .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
       .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
       .AutoCompleteCustomSource = I2cMonths
    End With
```

Comment: This is exactly the method started out with, as mentioned in the question. Moreover the question already has a selected answer that informs us that this exact approach *will not work* with a multi-line TextBox. Are you trying to add new information on a method to allow auto-complete to work with a multi-line TextBox?